# How are native applications (C, C++) deployed on android?

Tags: android, deployment

I am curious how to deploy android native (that is, using **android NDK** or **Qt C++**) application to the end users. AFAIK, the `apk` files are much like `jar` files, so I assume native programs can't be deployed this way. Or can they?

Is there any difference between raw Android NDK application and Qt native application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can and are - the native code libraries are packed into the apk and deployed with the 'wrapper' java app that is the entry point to running a NDK application.

Look at the Flow section of the [concepts guide.](http://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/concepts.html)